# How to resolve this sql script! The problem is that I need to get the newest record from a table column,But it is too slow. The Sql below:

Tags: mysql, sql, groupwise-maximum

Can someone help me to optimize this SQL? I am really appreciating it.

```
  SELECT
    gssur.id,
    date( gssur.create_time ) time,
    gssur.store_id,
    gssur.store_name,
    gssur.goods_id,
    gssur.spu_code,
    gssur.sku_code,
    gssur.goods_name,
    gssur.property_value,
    sum(
    IF
    ( gssur.data_source = 3 OR gssur.data_source = 4, ifnull( gssur.adjust_number, 0 ), 0 )) today_consumption,
    sum(
    IF
    ( gssur.data_source = 2 OR gssur.data_source = 1, ifnull( gssur.adjust_number, 0 ), 0 )) today_adjust_number,
    (
    SELECT
        adjust_after 
    FROM
        goods_store_stock_update_record 
    WHERE
        date( gssur.create_time ) = date( create_time ) 
        AND gssur.sku_code = sku_code 
        AND gssur.spu_code = spu_code 
        AND gssur.store_id = store_id 
    ORDER BY
        create_time DESC 
        LIMIT 1 
    ) today_surplus_stock 
FROM
    goods_store_stock_update_record gssur 
WHERE
    date( gssur.create_time ) = DATE( '2021-05-26' ) 
    AND gssur.is_del = 0 
GROUP BY
    time,
    gssur.sku_code,
    gssur.spu_code,
    gssur.store_id;
```

I am trying to find out the problem. when I removed the subquery:today_surplus_stock, It is extremely fast. So the main problem that we should focus on this situation.
The SQL means I want to query the Stores' newest inventory with a table named goods_store_stock_update_record for each one.
Table definition MYSQL below:

```
CREATE TABLE `goods_store_stock_update_record` (
  `id` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL COMMENT '主键',
  `store_id` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '门店id',
  `goods_id` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '商品id',
  `spu_code` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'spu编码',
  `sku_code` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'sku编码',
  `adjust_type` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '调整类型 1-增加 2-减少',
  `adjust_number` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '调整数量(正整数)',
  `adjust_before` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '调整前数量',
  `adjust_after` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '调整后数量',
  `data_source` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '数据来源 1-系统添加 2-手动添加 3-APP核销扣减 4-POS机核销扣减',
  `remarks` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '备注',
  `goods_name` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '商品名称',
  `property_value` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '属性值',
  `store_name` varchar(32) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '门店名称',
  `time_format` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '时间(年月日-yyyy-MM-dd)',
  `is_del` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '逻辑删除',
  `create_by` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '创建人',
  `create_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '创建时间',
  `update_by` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '修改人',
  `update_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '修改时间',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `ix2` (`sku_code`,`spu_code`,`store_id`,`create_time`),
  KEY `ix1` (`is_del`,`create_time`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC COMMENT='商品门店库存调整记录表';
```

There are no indexes created and the table counts are about 25193;
Explain's  Execution result below:

```
1   PRIMARY gssur       ALL                 30942   10.00   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  goods_store_stock_update_record     ALL                 30942   0.10    Using where; Using filesort
```

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.  Also: Is this mysql or Oracle? You have both tagged.

Comment: Than you so much, I will supplement the comment

Comment: This is for MySQL. I removed the Oracle tag.

Comment: On a side note: `DATE( '2021-05-26' )` is a date function invoked on a string, which involves internal data type conversion. Make this `DATE '2021-05-26'` which is just the date.

Comment: @thorstenkettner or just leave off the DATE bit altogether

Comment: @ Strawberry: Well, `'2021-05-26'` is a string that would get converted into a date. `DATE '2021-05-26'` is a date. So while both work, I'd still go with the standard SQL date literal.

Comment: Your query suggests that the table contains multiple rows per `sku_code, spu_code, store_id, date(create_time)`, but for every such group only one row has `is_del = 0`. Is this really the case? Otherwise you should fix your query first, before thinking about its speed.

Comment: There is a `create_time` in your query, but none in your `CREATE TABLE` statement,. In `CREATE TABLE` you have a `DATE` that you misname `time` instead. Can you please correct this in your request?

Comment: "There are no indexes created " - so why not do that?

Comment: See the tag [groupwisemaximum]

Answer (score 1):

### 1. Improving the performance of the main query

To improve the performance of the query you probably will need to rephrase the predicate:

```
date(gssur.create_time) = DATE('2021-05-26')`
```

as:

```
gssur.create_time >= '2021-05-26' and gssur.create_time < '2021-05-27'
```

This will promote the usage in the following index, that you'll need to create:

```
create index ix1 on goods_store_stock_update_record (is_del, create_time);
```

### 2. Improving the performance of the scalar subquery

In addition, your query as a scalar subquery in it. To increase the performance of this subquery you'll need to rephrase the condition

```
date( gssur.create_time ) = date( create_time )
```

as:

```
create_time >= date(gssur.create_time) and
create_time < date_add(date(gssur.create_time), interval 1 day)
```

This will promote the usage in the following index, that you'll need to create:

```
create index ix2 on goods_store_stock_update_record (
  sku_code, spu_code, store_id, create_time
);
```

Comment: @Strawberry There isn't any. That expression is equivalent.